# What is the significance of 10 digit signing identity identifier?

Tags: xcode, code-signing, keychain, provisioning-profile

I have one place within my app where I can expose a string to the user in the format:
`ABCDEFGHIJ.com.mycompany.myapp`.

The ABCDEFGHIJ part is the same number that I see in front of the keychain identities I use when sign my app in xCode.

**Should the 10 digit ABCDEFGHIJ identifier be kept secret? Are there security implications if someone can get their hands on it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it needn't be kept secret.  It's just a 'company ID'
Others can't sign an app  without your private key to access your app info from keychain even he knows the ID.

Or if he can know your app keychain info, it means he can access all other app info.